# Bootstrap 5 - Animated hamburger starting off as X

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-animations, bootstrap-5

I've used this approach to animate the hamburger button before with Bootstrap4. However, with bootstrap5, I'm seeing this odd behaviour of the icon starting off as 'X' and upon clicking, turns to the hamburger button. What is causing this and how can I fix it? There are quite a few blog posts on how to implement this, most of which target bs4, which works fine. I'm not quite sure what has changed between bs4 & bs5 that could have impacted this behaviour.

[JSFiddle to see the code in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/xou02Lkf/24/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="NavBar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </header>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

```css
.navbar-toggler span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #4f4f4f;
  height: 3px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
  transform-origin: center left;
}

.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(15%, -33%) rotate(45deg);
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(15%, 33%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(0deg);
}

.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(0deg);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please add collapsed class already on Toggler button. This is because Hamburger Menu icon is considered as collapsed already and when you click on it , it will be activated or in action. so Initially make it collapsed.
If you need anything else, please let me know in comments.

Change this

```
         <button class="navbar-toggler">
```

to

```
         <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed">
```

and it will be done.

See this in Action here.

```css
.navbar-toggler span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #4f4f4f;
  height: 3px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
  transform-origin: center left;
}



.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(0deg);
}

.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(0deg);
}

.navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(15%, -33%) rotate(45deg);
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(15%, 33%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="NavBar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </header>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```